# jQuery on hover of a link show hidden div

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to show some hidden content when a link is hovered. The content is unique per link. I have it working fine but I know the jQuery code is awful. I think ".this" is the secret but I can't make it work. Any thoughts? This is the most ugly inefficient crap jQuery ever but I am trying to figure this out. Thanks!

jQuery

```
          $(document).ready
      (
        function(){
            $(".short-term-trigger").hover(function(){
             $(".short-term").toggleClass("visible");
             });
          }
    )

    $(document).ready
      (
        function(){
            $(".medium-term-trigger").hover(function(){
             $(".medium-term").toggleClass("visible");
             });
          }
    )

    $(document).ready
      (
        function(){
            $(".long-term-trigger").hover(function(){
             $(".long-term").toggleClass("visible");
             });
          }
    )

    $(document).ready
      (
        function(){
            $(".retirement-trigger").hover(function(){
             $(".retirement").toggleClass("visible");
             });
          }
    )
```

HTML

```
<ul id="goal-btns">
            <li><a class="short-term-trigger" href="#">Short-Term Gains</a></li>
            <li><a class="medium-term-trigger" href="#">Medium Term Goals</a></li>
            <li><a class="long-term-trigger" href="#">Long Term Goals</a></li>
            <li><a class="retirement-trigger" href="#">Retirement</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="talk-bubble hang-left short-term">
            <p class="bubble-text">I’ll need the money is less than 12 months.</p>
        </div><!--/short-gains-->

        <div class="talk-bubble hang-right medium-term">
            <p class="bubble-text">I don’t need the money immediately but may need it within the next 6-10 years.</p>
        </div><!--/short-gains-->

        <div class="talk-bubble hang-right long-term">
            <p class="bubble-text">I’m investing for the long-term.</p>
        </div><!--/short-gains-->

        <div class="talk-bubble hang-right retirement">
            <p class="bubble-text">I’m investing for my retirement.</p>
        </div><!--/short-gains-->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#goal-btns li a').hover(function() {
        var cls = this.className.replace('-trigger', '');
        $("."+cls).toggleClass("visible");
    });
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2NnX9/

Comment: Naturally, this relies on the word `-trigger` to exist. Meaning if you or someone else ever change class names the code is going to break. If you want to associate elements a neutral alternative could be data attributes as mentioned by Alexander as well. Regardless of HTML5 they can be selecting using jQuery's `.data()` or `attr()`. Off course that alternative is a no-go if you are writing HTML which must pass none HTML 5 doc type validation.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Yes, that's correct, in case that classes should be changed using `data-*` can be better and maintaining them is easier. I just minified the code according to existing markup. However instead of `data` there are many other alternatives, like using href attributes of anchors.

Comment: @undefined: Completely forgot to +1 for nice short version of the script and the working demo as usual.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Oh, thank-you man, I was about to upvote your good answer, but you deleted it.

Comment: @undefined: No worries, I answered but after I did and refreshed the page I saw that `Alexander` already covered data attributes. I found it a bit overkill to add another answer repeating the exact same thing. `Alexander` was faster :)

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, the usage of `data-*` attributes is common for hold relevant information about the events associated to an element.

First you could use an data-attribute to keep track of the elements you want to apply an action to, `data-linker`.

```
<a data-linker href="#">Retirement</a>
```

And an alternative data-attribute holding a relevant information i.e. options related to the action to be applied, `data-linker-target`.

```
<a data-linker data-linker-target=".retirement" href="#">Retirement</a>
```

A basic jQuery function may be:

```
$.fn.linker = function(){
  return this.each(function(){
    var $this = $(this), data = $this.data(), $target = $(data.linkerTarget);
    $this.hover(function(){
      $target.toggleClass("visible");
    });
  });
};
```

Usage:

```
$("[data-linker]").linker();
```

Comment: This is great. I am going to look into using this in the future is it for HTML5 only?

Comment: @MarkMitchell, they are not HTML4 valid, but they won't cause any problem. Take into account that while using `data-*` attributes you won't pass a validator using a non-HTML5 doctype though, iirc

Answer (score 0):

You weren't that off except for all the document.ready.

[Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/xCSbR/)

Here's the code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".short-term-trigger").hover(function(){
                 $(".short-term").toggle();
            });

      $(".medium-term-trigger").hover(function(){
                $(".medium-term").toggle();
            });

     $(".long-term-trigger").hover(function(){
             $(".long-term").toggle();
             });

      $(".retirement-trigger").hover(function(){
             $(".retirement").toggle();
             });
 })
```

But if you really want to optimize, you'll use [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xCSbR/2/).

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#goal-btns li a").hover(function(){
                 $('div.' + $(this).attr('data-ref')).toggle();
            });

 })
```

You just need to add an attribute data-ref to your  element.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to reduce all that jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".short-term-trigger,.medium-term-trigger,.long-term-trigger,.retirement-trigger").hover(function() {
        $("." + $(this).attr('class').slice(0, -8)).toggleClass("visible");
    });
});​
```

**[​jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/VrWTX/)**